# illegal operation on empty resut set

Tags: java

I get "*Illegal operation on empty result set*" whenever I execute this code for the first time when the database base is empty, but the values still get stored in the database. When I re-run the code, I get "Duplicate entry '1000' for key 1". What can I do to make the code run smoothly both when I run it when there are no values at the database and when I re-run consecutively?

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(id);    
rs.next();
int custId =1000;
if(rs.wasNull()) { 
    custId = 1000;
} else {
    custId =  rs.getInt(8)+1;
}                       
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setString(2, fname);
ps.setString(6, phone);
ps.setString(4, email);
ps.setString(5, sex);
ps.setString(7, date);
ps.setString(3, address);
ps.setInt(8, custId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(id);
boolean thisResultSetHasRecords;
if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
  thisResultSetHasRecords = true;
  while(rs.next()) {
    //do stuff with every record,
    //rs.next() returns false if empty or after last
  }
} else {
  thisResultSetHasRecords = false;
}
```

This one

```
rs.wasNull()
```

checks if a column of an existing row (->non empty ResultSet) had the SQL value NULL, not to be confused with Java null.

Also, you probably won't need to manually increment the id field; you can just make the field in the table AUTO_INCREMENT to avoid the second error -> See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp